# how to add MTPROTO proxy to Guzzle

Tags: php, proxy, guzzle, mtproto

I'm using Guzzle in my php project , I like to set proxy for guzzle with mtproto.

can I do that? 
as you know MTproto proxies has a server address , a port and a secret key to connect , how to should pass these three parameter to guzzle to use that, if it's ever support such kind of proxies ever?